# Change Pin Icons in Bing Maps

Tags: bing, bing-maps

Is it possible to change the icons for pushpins in "My Places"?

If I import a Google Maps kml I can see the custom icons from Goole but I can't figure out how to change them in Bing Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's not possible in the current version.